# How to get the sum of a java arraylist?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SalesAnalysis{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        double weeklySales, weeklyAverage,totalSales;
        weeklySales=0;
        totalSales=0;
        int week=1;

        File file =new File("/");

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);
        String str;
        
        while(inFile.hasNext())
        {
                str=inFile.nextLine();
                String[] data= str.split(",");
                weeklySales=0;
                double sum=0;
                for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                weeklySales=weeklySales+Double.parseDouble(data[i]);
                Double.parseDouble(data[i]);
                sum=sum+Double.parseDouble(data[i]);}
                
                System.out.printf("Week"+week+"total Sales %,.2f\n",weeklySales);
                System.out.printf("Week"+week+"daily average sales %,.2f\n",weeklySales/7);
                
                System.out.printf("totalSales for all weeks %,.2f\n ",sum);
                totalSales=totalSales+weeklySales;
                week++;
                
        }
        
        
        inFile.close();



}
```

}

output:Week1total Sales 12,092.75
Week1daily average sales 1,727.54
totalSales for all weeks 12,092.75
Week2total Sales 27,461.00
Week2daily average sales 3,923.00
totalSales for all weeks 27,461.00
Week3total Sales 12,058.34
Week3daily average sales 1,722.62
totalSales for all weeks 12,058.34

here is the file:
1245.67,1490.07,1679.87,2371.46,1783.92,1461.99,2059.77
2541.36,2965.88,1965.32,1845.23,7021.11,9652.74,1469.36
2513.45,1963.22,1568.35,1966.35,1893.25,1025.36,1128.36

Comment: Why the result of sum is as same as the the result of weektotal? @NikolaiDmitriev

Comment: because you set it to 0 at the beginning of every loop

Comment: but i also need to calculate The total sales for each week @NikolaiDmitriev

Comment: like this it gives you the total sum, true. you'd have to set it to 0 only if the week changes, from the current data[i] compared with the last one. a classical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop misses braces (`for (...){code here}`). It only sees the immediate next line (`weeklySales...`) as belonging to it, but not the second. So `i` is not in scope there.

Then you're using an array, not a list, you access it using `data[i]` rather than `data.get(i)`